# Create numpy array from matrix declared inside .m matlab file

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, numpy

A coworker left some data files I want to analyze with Numpy.

Each file is a matlab file, say `data.m`, and have the following formatting (but with a lot more columns and rows):

```
values = [-24.92 -23.66 -22.55 ;
-24.77 -23.56 -22.45 ;
-24.54 -23.64 -22.56 ;
];
```

which is the typical explicit matrix creation syntax used by matlab.

My question is: what would be the most practical way to create a numpy array from these files?

I could think about a "brute force" or a "quick and dirty" solution, but if there would be a more straightforward one, I would much rather use it, like a standard function from numpy or even from another module.

EDIT: I noticed that my files may contain `NaN` values, so I most probably will adapt the answers given to use `numpy.genfromtxt` instead of `numpy.loadtxt`. I plan to include my final code as soon as I have it.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I ended up with the following code, where I get everything between `[]` using regex, and create a numpy array using `genfromtxt` in order to handle NaN. A shorter solution could be to use `fromstring` method, which does not need StringIO, but this cannot handle NaN, and my data have NaN :oP

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import numpy, re, StringIO

with open('data.m') as f:
    s = re.search('\[(.*)\]', f.read(), re.DOTALL).group(1)
    buf = StringIO.StringIO(s)
    a = numpy.genfromtxt(buf, missing_values='NaN', filling_values=numpy.nan)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple options, although neither is built in.

## The solution you probably do not find acceptable

This solution probably falls into your "quick and dirty" category, but it helps lead in to the next solution.

Remove the `values = [`, the last line (`];`), and globally replace all `;` with nothing to get:

```
-24.92 -23.66 -22.55 
-24.77 -23.56 -22.45 
-24.54 -23.64 -22.56
```

Then you can use numpy's `loadtxt` as follows.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.loadtxt('data.m')

>>> A
array([[-24.92, -23.66, -22.55],
       [-24.77, -23.56, -22.45],
       [-24.54, -23.64, -22.56]])
```

## A solution you might find acceptable

In this solution, we create a method to coerce the input data into a form that numpy `loadtxt` likes (the same form as above, actually).

```
import StringIO
import numpy as np

def convert_m(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
        arrstr = fin.read()
    arrstr = arrstr.split('[', 1)[-1] # remove the content up to the first '['
    arrstr = arrstr.rsplit(']', 1)[0] # remove the content after ']'
    arrstr = arrstr.replace(';', '\n') # replace ';' with newline
    return StringIO.StringIO(arrstr)
```

Now that we have that, do the following.

```
>>> np.loadtxt(convert_m('data.m'))
array([[-24.92, -23.66, -22.55],
       [-24.77, -23.56, -22.45],
       [-24.54, -23.64, -22.56]])
```

Comment: Your answer was more or less the kind of thing I was considering. Today I am already tired, but tomorrow I will take a look to find out what suits me best. Besides, since my question prompts to generic methods, I will think about a good generic method, but probably `loadtxt` should be used anyway in these cases. Thanks, and accepted for now!

Answer (score 1):

You could feed an iterator to `np.genfromtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
import re

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = (re.sub(r'[^-+.0-9 ]+', '', line) for line in f)
    arr = np.genfromtxt(lines)

print(arr)
```

yields

```
[[-24.92 -23.66 -22.55]
 [-24.77 -23.56 -22.45]
 [-24.54 -23.64 -22.56]]
```

[Thanks to Bitwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17933417/190597) for clueing me in to this answer.

Comment: Actually, the file you mention is a .mat file which contains matlab variables that can be loaded inside a matlab script. The file I have is (unfortunately) a .m file, which contains matlab source code (i.e., it is the script). If I were using matlab instead of numpy, I should "import" the .m file inside the running script, so that its code would be executed creating the matrix named `values` in the global namespace, but I am using Numpy, so... :o(

Comment: That is a very professional answer. I will need a time to grasp its power, but for sure it gave me some deeper insights. Thank you very much!