# taking mean of data read in 'error cannot perform reduce with flexible type' python

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I am trying to read in data from a text file and take the mean of this data, but I am getting the error cannot perform reduce with flexible type. I dont know why, can somebody please help. here is my code.

```
right=open('01phi.txt','r').readlines()  
right=str(right) 
a=np.asarray(right)
b=np.mean(a)
print b
```

**EDIT**: I am now using this line
`right=np.genfromtxt('01phi.txt')`
but it produces this error `Line #10 (got 3 columns instead of 7)` as this line in the array is not as big. [Using genfromtxt to import csv data with missing values in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761103/using-genfromtxt-to-import-csv-data-with-missing-values-in-numpy) this link tells my how to ignore the bottom line or how to fill it in but both of these methods would sque the mean. is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`right` is a string. `np.asarray(some_string)` returns an array with string dtype. NumPy's `np.mean` function raises a TypeError when passed an array of string dtype.

```
In [29]: np.asarray('1 2 3')
Out[29]: 
array('1 2 3', 
      dtype='|S5')
In [31]: np.mean(a)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Instead, use [np.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or [np.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) to load an array from a text file:

```
a = np.genfromtxt(filename, ...)
```

Comment: Yes this should work for me but I have an error when using genfromtxt it says  Line #12 (got 2 columns instead of 5) as there are less numbers in my bottom line of the text file. But i just want all the numbers to be imported in to one array. I dont know how to get arorund this

Comment: this tells me how to ignore the bottom values or fill the missing values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761103/using-genfromtxt-to-import-csv-data-with-missing-values-in-numpy but its imortant that i dont because this will sque the mean. is there a way i can get around this?

Comment: There is a way to pass [custom file-like objects to `np.genfromtxt`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923214/7923287#7923287). You could use something like that to process the short lines and return full lines instead. However, I think that is more code than you'd really want to use here. I think it would be easier to just write a preprocessing script which rewrites your old data file (by adding zeros into the missing columns) into one that can be read by np.genfromtxt.