# Using numpy.genfromtxt to read a csv file with strings containing commas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, genfromtxt

I am trying to read in a csv file with `numpy.genfromtxt` but some of the fields are strings which contain commas.  The strings are in quotes, but numpy is not recognizing the quotes as defining a single string.  For example, with the data in 't.csv':

```
2012, "Louisville KY", 3.5
2011, "Lexington, KY", 4.0
```

the code

```
np.genfromtxt('t.csv', delimiter=',')
```

produces the error:

> ValueError: Some errors were detected !
>       Line #2 (got 4 columns instead of 3)

The data structure I am looking for is:

```
array([['2012', 'Louisville KY', '3.5'],
       ['2011', 'Lexington, KY', '4.0']], 
      dtype='|S13')
```

Looking over the documentation, I don't see any options to deal with this.  Is there a way do to it with numpy, or do I just need to read in the data with the `csv` module and then convert it to a numpy array?

Comment: can you post more of the full csv, I think I know how to fix your problem ;)

Comment: You should change your csv replacing the separating character from `,` to `;` for example...

Comment: @SaulloCastro: I can't do that because my real data is much messier and has strings with `;` and/or any other character you can think of - this is only a toy example.  What I am looking for is a more general solution.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf: As I mentioned, this is just a toy example to illustrate the problem, but I think it has all the essential features.  What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4384) (the becoming default library for working with dataframes (heterogeneous data) in scientific python) for this. It's [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) can handle this. From the docs:

> quotechar : string
>
> ```
> The character to used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted items 
> can include the delimiter and it will be ignored.
> ```

The default value is `"`. An example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [3]: s="""year, city, value
   ...: 2012, "Louisville KY", 3.5
   ...: 2011, "Lexington, KY", 4.0"""

In [4]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
Out[4]:
   year           city  value
0  2012  Louisville KY    3.5
1  2011  Lexington, KY    4.0
```

The trick here is that you also have to use `skipinitialspace=True` to deal with the spaces after the comma-delimiter.

Apart from a powerful csv reader, I can also strongly advice to use pandas with the heterogeneous data you have (the example output in numpy you give are all strings, although you could use structured arrays).

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm.  I have heard a bit about `pandas` but have never gotten around to trying before - this seems like a great opportunity.  And BTW, I was trying to keep my initial example simple, but I was actually planning to use `np.recfromcsv` to get structured numpy arrays.

Answer (score 15):

The problem with the additional comma, `np.genfromtxt` does not deal with that.

One simple solution is to read the file with `csv.reader()` from python's [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module into a list and then dump it into a numpy array if you like.

If you really want to use `np.genfromtxt`, note that it can take iterators instead of files, e.g. `np.genfromtxt(my_iterator, ...)`. So, you can wrap a `csv.reader` in an iterator and give it to `np.genfromtxt`.

That would go something like this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

np.genfromtxt(("\t".join(i) for i in csv.reader(open('myfile.csv'))), delimiter="\t")
```

This essentially replaces on-the-fly only the appropriate commas with tabs.

Comment: Well, I see what you're getting at here, but I played around a bit but still couldn't get it to work quite right.  Anyway, I think today I'm going with the `pandas` route.  Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a numpy you probably want to work with numpy.ndarray. This will give you a numpy.ndarray:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('file.csv').as_matrix()
```

Pandas will handle the "Lexington, KY" case correctly

Comment: Note that If you do this, the first row could be lost. The first row is treated as the column labels of the dataframe.

Comment: `as_matrix()` will be deprecated soon. Use `.values` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Make a better function that combines the power of the standard [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) and Numpy's `recfromcsv`. For instance, the `csv` module has good control and customization of dialects, quotes, escape characters, etc., which you can add to the example below.

The example `genfromcsv_mod` function below reads in a complicated CSV file similar to what Microsoft Excel sees, which may contain commas within quoted fields. Internally, the function has a generator function that rewrites each row with tab delimiters.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def recfromcsv_mod(fname, **kwargs):
    def rewrite_csv_as_tab(fname):
        with open(fname, newline='') as fp:
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(fp.read(1024))
            fp.seek(0)
            for row in csv.reader(fp, dialect):
                yield "\t".join(row)
    return np.recfromcsv(
        rewrite_csv_as_tab(fname), delimiter="\t", encoding=None, **kwargs)

# Use it to read a CSV file into a record array
x = recfromcsv_mod("t.csv", case_sensitive=True)
```

Comment: I believe it should be `open(fname, 'r')` as otherwise it throws an error with passing bytes instead of strings

Comment: @Guillaume thanks, this was for Python 2, but has been updated for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this code. We are reading .csv file from np.genfromtext()
> method
> **Code:**

```
myfile = np.genfromtxt('MyData.csv', delimiter = ',')
myfile = myfile.astype('int64')
print(myfile)
```

> **Output:**

```
[[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
 [ 3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3]
 [ 3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3]
 [ 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4]
 [ 5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5]
 [ 6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6]
 [ 7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7]
 [ 8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8]
 [ 9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9]
 [10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10]
 [11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11]
 [12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12]
 [13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13]
 [14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14]
 [15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]]
```

> **Input File "MyData.csv"**

[image]