# numpy genfromtxt/pandas read_csv; ignore commas within quote marks

Tags: python, file-io, numpy, pandas, genfromtxt

Consider a file, `a.dat`, with contents:

```
address 1, address 2, address 3, num1, num2, num3
address 1, address 2, address 3, 1.0, 2.0, 3
address 1, address 2, "address 3, address4", 1.0, 2.0, 3
```

I am trying to import with [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). However the function sees an additional column in row 3. I get a similar error with [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
np.genfromtxt('a.dat',delimiter=',',dtype=None,skiprows=1)

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #3 (got 7 columns instead of 6)
```

and

```
pandas read_csv sort of works - but it gives me an unaligned data structure:

pd.read_csv('a.dat')

pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 3, saw 7
```

I'm trying to find an input parameter to compensate for this. I don't mind if I end up with a numpy ndarray or pandas dataframe.

**Is there a parameter that I can set within `genfromtxt` and/or `read_csv` that will let me ignore the comma within the speech marks?**

I note that `read_csv` includes a `quotechar='"'` parameter, defined thus:

> **quotechar** : string (length 1) The character used to denote the start
>   and end of a quoted item. Quoted items can include the delimiter and
>   it will be ignored.

This reads to me like read_csv should work for my case by default - yet it doesn't.

I can see that I could pre-process the file to strip out the commas - I'd like to avoid that if possible but would welcome suggestions if this is the only way.

Comment: why does quotechar doesn't work ? anybody ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942117/1461850):

The key parameter that I was missing is `skipinitialspace=True` - this "deals with the spaces after the comma-delimiter"

```
a=pd.read_csv('a.dat',quotechar='"',skipinitialspace=True)

   address 1  address 2            address 3  num1  num2  num3
0  address 1  address 2            address 3     1     2     3
1  address 1  address 2  address 3, address4     1     2     3
```

This works :-)

Answer (score 2):

Python's built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module can deal with this kind of data.

```
with open("a.dat") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)
    dtype = numpy.dtype(zip(header, ['S20', 'S20', 'S20', 'f8', 'f8', 'f8']))
    data = numpy.fromiter(itertools.imap(tuple, reader), dtype=dtype)
```