# Reading CSV file containing list of dict in quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that have this line:

```
"Venta presencial",53232907737,"[{"was_pin":false,"pin_validation":"pin_not_validated","integration":"none","is_fallback":false}]"
```

When I read the file with `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding='utf-8')
```

I expect 3 columns, but I receive 6 columns

I need to ignore the separator "," when its inside of double quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy genfromtxt/pandas read\_csv; ignore commas within quote marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079304/numpy-genfromtxt-pandas-read-csv-ignore-commas-within-quote-marks)

Comment: Can ' " ' be " ' " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48672386/20866830), Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

for_pd = StringIO()
with open(f'PATH/csv1.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        new_line = re.sub(r',', '|', line.rstrip(), count=2)
        print (new_line, file=for_pd)

for_pd.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(for_pd, sep='|', names=["A","B","C"])
df.head()
```