# loading data from csv ,genfromtxt, numpy, delimiter

Tags: python, csv, numpy, machine-learning

I am just starting out in numpy. I am trying to load data from a csv file using numpy.I have lines in the data in this format

**Input Format:**

```
 893,3,"kelly,Mr. James",male,34.5.
```

I am using **genfromtxt** to load it using `delimiter = ','` , `dtypes = None`.

But using this loads the data as below:

```
893,3,'"kelly,' , ',Mr. James"', 'male', 34,5.
```

**Expected Output:**

`893,3,"kelly,Mr. James",'male',34,5`.

Dont know how to use delimiters properly for this.

Comment: Have a look at this post at stackoverflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933282/using-numpy-genfromtxt-to-read-a-csv-file-with-strings-containing-commas