# How can I read csv file with np.genfromtxt()?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have a csv file and I have to read this in jupyter notebook with np.genfromtxt(). (Unfortunately, I cannot use pd.read_csv() and even other pandas functions or methods.)
Instead of showing you the file, let me give you an example.
The file is as below:

```py
Item,Color,Price
iPhone,Red,"1,000"
Galaxy,Black,"1,100"
```

I made a code that can read such csv file as:

```py
def csv_opener(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
        num_col = len(first_line.split(','))
    
    return np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',', dtype=None, usecols=range(num_col))
```

You can see there are commas in Price values. But since delimiter is set as a comma, the "csv_opener" function reads the file as:

```py
iPhone | Red | '"1' | '000"'
```

Here are the questions.

1. How can I make my "csv_opener" function recognize double-quoted value as one?
   (not '"1' | '000"' -> '1,000')
2. How can I change the data type after reading them? (not '1,000' -> numeric types such as integer/float)

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [Using numpy.genfromtxt to read a csv file with strings containing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17933282/1609514). I used google search to find this.

Comment: genfrontxt doesn't handle quotes.  The newest `loadtxt` does

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module.

```
cat phone.csv                                                                                                                                                              
Item,Color,Price
iPhone,Red,"1,000"
Galaxy,Black,"1,100"

import csv

with open('phone.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
    c_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in c_reader:
        print(row)

['Item', 'Color', 'Price']
['iPhone', 'Red', '1,000']
['Galaxy', 'Black', '1,100']
```

CSV is a text format so the only type you will get out of it is string. You can create something like a database table with specific types that you transfer the data to. Though this depends on the string representations being consistent and correct for the receiving type.